# Chromium proxy only https

Tags: node.js, proxy, puppeteer, chromium

I use mac os & chromium 80.0.3987.0 and I have problem with proxy.
When I start for example: `./Chromium --proxy-server=123.123.123.123:8888` and open **https** page I have proxied IP but when I open **http** I have my own ip! What's wrong?

How to get proxy on both http & https and return error in other cases to prevent connecting from own IP? I use it also with puppeteer.

http://whatismyip.host/ - no proxy
https://whatismyipaddress.com/ - with proxy

Comment: are you using a socks5 proxy?

Comment: @mbit no, http proxy

Comment: I can't tell what's going on without any info on the setup, but if you have ssh access to the server I can show a simple way of proxying http/https.

Comment: @mbit localhost, random proxy for each request, mac os & no more configuration than this - this should work for http & https

Comment: I meant the proxy server setup. I just tested chromium with an http proxy and it shows the proxy addresses in both cases.

Comment: @mbit i tested random proxy - so it's probably problem with proxy server, so am I able to block somehow no proxied requests?